# How to click and open the calendar on page in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select the date by clicking the below. However when I try to find the `element` and `click` I get no errors but the calendar on page doesn't open.

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here or is there a way to directly input the date?

```
                <div class="was-bold-text">To</div>
                <div class="was-date-container was-light-text" data-displaydate="End Date">
    <input name="" value="" id="was-returns-reconciliation-report-end-date" type="date" class="was-form-control was-input-date" data-defaultdate="" data-mindate="" data-maxdate="today" data-placeholder="End Date" max="2020-02-12" min="2020-02-04">
    
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('was-returns-reconciliation-report-end-date').click()
# No error thrown but the calender view doesn't open either.

driver.find_element_by_class_name('was-date-container').click()
# No error thrown but the calender view doesn't open either.
```

What would be the way to select the date or open the calender and click the date required?

Comment: I have found a working solution for now. i.e. find the element and sendkeys to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem a while ago and solved by setting the datePicker value by javascript. Its not the click you are looking but might work for your problem in C# is something like this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('was-returns-reconciliation-report-end-date').value='2020-01-05'");
```

So in python would be like this I guess, maybe some syntax error:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('was-returns-reconciliation-report-end-date').value = '2020-01-05'")
```

Comment: Not working for me. It isn't throwing an error but the date is not changing and when I click on the next button it says date cannot be blank.

Comment: Doesn´t work with all the datePickers , could be the Date Format as well, edited it matching the format of the dpicker. If doesn´t work go with other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to click on date picker because its a native input element not plugin like datepicker or datetimepicker. But you can set the value by follwoing method,

```
datepicker = driver.find_element_by_id('was-returns-reconciliation-report-end-date')
datepicker.clear() # clear values if any.
datepicker.send_keys("02/12/2020")
```

I think this will work for you.